# Expressjs how to show / hide a div in case user its logged

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, forms-authentication, express

I followed this example -> https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/auth

Works fine, but I dont like the way they display the content one time you successfully logged in or logged  out.

Its there other way to do X or Y one time user its authenticated ? Example

I have a linear form for login, will be nice to hide that div one time user it's authenticated, but I can't do this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(req.session.user) { $(.class of teh frm to hide).hide(); }
}
```

I tried too 
    session.user

All the time tells me its undefined. I placed this on layout.

So how I show things on a view if user its authenticated or, if user it's admin ??

Cause atm the only way I see it's authorizate some routes and display specific content via

```
req.session.success = 'Authenticated as ' + req.session.user.name
  + ' click to <a href="/logout">logout</a>. '
  + ' You may now access <a href="/restricted">/restricted</a>.';
}
```

Think its not the way to go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is better to use your template engine to show different contents instead of client-side javascript. If you are using jade, do the following:

In your app.js create a variable that is passed to every view if the user is logged in:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  // all the stuff from the example
  if (req.session.user) {
    res.locals.user = req.session.user
  }
  next();
});
```

Use this variable in your template engine (for example jade):

```
if user
  // show stuff here
else
  // for everyone else
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `app.locals.user` rather than `res.locals.user` or is there actually a different scope?