# Replace login/sign up buttons with logout button when user logs in (EJS template)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs, templating

I've successfully created my first web application using Node, EJS and MongoDB.

I want to hide my login/sign up links when user logs in and want to display logout button in my header file.

Anybody got a solution? I've already tried [Expressjs how to show / hide a div in case user its logged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457615/expressjs-how-to-show-hide-a-div-in-case-user-its-logged)
But for some reason, the user variable in ejs file is initialising to null, so only one case is exectuting

Here is my header.ejs file:

```
<h1><a href="/">RideShare</a></h1>

<ul>
    
    
    <li><a href="/find">Find a ride</a></li>
    <li><a href="/create">Create a ride</a></li>
    <li><a href="/myrides">My rides</a></li>
    <%if (!user) { %>
        <li><a href="/login">Sign in</a></li>
        <li><a href="/register">Sign Up</a></li>
        <% }else{ %>
            <form action="/logout?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                <button type="submit">Log Out</button>
            </form>
            <%}%>
    
</ul>
```

Comment: did you render header.ejs like this ? `res.render('header.jes', { user })` and where user data comes ?

Comment: I actually used express-ejs-layouts so I used layout.ejs file inside which I included header.ejs. So I don't know how to pass 'user' to header.ejs directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should set user data after login in local session

server.js

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
});
```

headers.ejs

```
<h1><a href="/">RideShare</a></h1>

<ul>
    
    
    <li><a href="/find">Find a ride</a></li>
    <li><a href="/create">Create a ride</a></li>
    <li><a href="/myrides">My rides</a></li>
    <%if (!locals.session.loggedin) { %>
        <li><a href="/login">Sign in</a></li>
        <li><a href="/register">Sign Up</a></li>
        <% }else{ %>
            <form action="/logout?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                <button type="submit">Log Out</button>
            </form>
            <%}%>
    
</ul>
```

and put this in your login API

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    req.session.loggedin = true
})
```

Comment: could you explain where exactly to put 'req.session.loggedin = true'. I'm really sorry I am new to webdev

Comment: if you have a login form , there is a POST endpoint to check login something like `<form action="/login" method="post">` , routes something like this `router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    req.session.loggedin = true
})`

Comment: Hey, Thanks for clearing my doubt. On last thing, I'm getting this error in the console. Any idea how to fix this?
` >> 10|     <%if (!req.session.loggedin) { %>`
`req is not defined`

Comment: Hey there, thanks again. It solved the error but it's still the same. I figured out that 'req.session.loggedin = true' is not updating because I'm using passport for authentication. my Login API looks like this: `router.post('/',checkNotAuthenticated,passport.authenticate('local',{
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true
    }))` So how do I update req.session.loggedin

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your header.js

   ```
    router.get('/', (req,res) => {
        res.render('header',  { isAuthenticated: req.isAuthenticated() })
    });
   ```

   The isAuthenticated() is a method provided by passportJS
2. Then go to your header.ejs and add:

   ```
        <%if (isAuthenticated) { %>
           <!--Logout-->  
        <% }else{ %>
        <!--Sign In/Register--> 
        <%}%>
   ```